# If $v_2,v_3$ are linearly independent then $Sp(v_1,v_2)\neq Sp(v_1,v_3)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have this question:

> Prove or disprove.
> There's a vectorspace V and there's $v_1,v_2,v_3$ ($v_1 \neq v_2 \neq v_3$) vectors in V.
> If $v_2,v_3$ are linearly independent then $Sp(v_1,v_2)\neq Sp(v_1,v_3)$.

We're given that: $v_2\neq v_3$ and we're given that $v_2,v_3$ are linearly independent, meaning: $\lambda v_2+ \lambda v_3=0$ where $\lambda=0$ is the only solution.

We'll prove it by contradiction. Assume $Sp(v_1,v_2)=Sp(v_1,v_3)$ but since we were given $v_2 \neq v_3$ then indeed $Sp(v_1,v_2) \neq Sp(v_1,v_3)$.

I feel like its incorrect, I didn't make any use of that they're linearly independent, So I was thinking maybe on another way.

I found this sentence in my book: We know that $Sp(K)=Sp(T)$ (when T,K are subsets of V) only and only if $K \subseteq Sp(T)$ and $T \subseteq Sp(K)$, And I was thinking on negating it: $Sp(K) \neq Sp(T) \Rightarrow K \nsubseteq Sp(T)$ or $T \nsubseteq Sp(K)$.

And Approach this problem as:
$K= \{ v_1,v_2 \} , T= \{ v_1,v_3 \}$ where $T,K \subseteq V$, but since $v_2\neq v_3$ then $K\nsubseteq Sp(T) \Rightarrow T \nsubseteq Sp(K)$.

And its again similar to my first solution. What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the statement is correct? Try to make some examples like in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$ to grasp it better. The first prove you provided isn't tue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is false. In $\mathbb R^{2}$ take $v_1=(1,1), v_2=(1,0), v_3=(0,1)$.  In this case, $span (v_1,v_2)=span (v_1,v_3)=\mathbb R^{2}$.